# Should I install Ubuntu in my laptop? Was confused with 2GHz duo core requirement when downloading iso

Tags: system-installation, laptop, intel-graphics, hp, intel

Specs:

It's 7/8 years old laptop and perfectly works on Win10... cannot update to 11.

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz /  2.30 GHz(Base Speed)  / 2cores

4GB RAM DDR3 1600Mhz x 2

512 GB SSD

2GB Intel(R) HD Graphics Family

Comment: The Ubuntu Desktop installer includes a "Try Ubuntu" environment that does NOT touch your hard drive. Try it, see if it works with your hardware, see if you like it.

Comment: That is an UEFI based system. but with only 4GB you may like a lightweight flavor better. It used to be that 4GB was plenty for Ubuntu, but Ubuntu now expects newer systems. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie  I like Kubuntu which is more middle weight. It even has worked on my very old 2006 laptop (but only as a test, did not use a lot as system has no batteries. But Kubuntu also works well on my brand new system.